# How can I get a line fit data of distplot of seaborn in for loop?

Tags: python, seaborn

I try to get the line data of distplot in seaborn in for loop.
but when I execute this code it prints same values even though all elements of list X are different.
please let me know why this happen

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = np.random.normal(10,3,size=100)
x2 = np.random.normal(8,2,size=100)
x3 = np.random.normal(7,2,size=100)
x4 = np.random.normal(11,5,size=100)

X = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

for i in X:
    dist_data_1 = sns.distplot(i).get_lines()[0].get_data()
    print(dist_data_1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plotting all the distribution on the same axes, so you are adding new lines at each iteration. However, you are always retrieving the data from the first line (index `[0]`).

Instead, you should retrieve the data from the *last* line (index `[-1]`):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = np.random.normal(10,3,size=100)
x2 = np.random.normal(8,2,size=100)
x3 = np.random.normal(7,2,size=100)
x4 = np.random.normal(11,5,size=100)

X = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

for i in X:
    dist_data_1 = sns.distplot(i).get_lines()[-1].get_data()
    print(dist_data_1)
```

Comment: So in this case `sns.distplot(i)` doesnt create a new instance on each iteration?

Comment: `distplot()` plots on the *current axes*, so no, it does not create new axes everytime, it just superimposes new data onto the existing axes (matplotlib automatically creates a new axes at the first iteration if there is no *current axes* available).

Comment: It works! thank you. I have been ignoring the axes problems.

Comment: @YongHwanKim You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)